# View TPM PCR contents on Windows

Tags: windows, tpm

How do I view the PCR register contents on Windows? On Linux, you `cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/pcrs`, but I cannot find the Windows equivalent.

Comment: Answer at [trusted computing - TPM PCR Generation in Windows - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180166/tpm-pcr-generation-in-windows)